# What is the right way to avoid shamap corruption when converting mercurial repositories?

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to build a pruned Mercurial repository from a larger one and need to pull in changes from several branches.  I want to use `hg convert`, but I am getting errors like

> abort: unknown revision '81b79760e1350d185dbf645ab67633eda9d52ada'!

when try to use `convert` to get changes from a related branch.  Here's what I did.  I started with *mybranch* and used

> hg convert --filemap *filemap* mybranch mybranch_converted

Then, to capture any changes to the paired down converted repository from *anotherbranch* (that shares a common ancestor with *mybranch*), I invoked

> hg convert --filemap *filemap* anotherbranch mybranch_converted

but that fails with an abort error like the one I showed above.

I am lead to understand that this indicates that the *shamap* file created by the first conversion is borked somehow, so what should I do to generate a good *shamap* file?  I'd also be interested in knowing what could cause this process to fail considering that it is so straight forward.  Also, as this may be relevant, I should note that the ancestor of *mybranch* and *anotherbranch* was itself generated by converting yet another Mercurial repository.

Answer (score 2):

I think that message is telling you that one of the changesets you're pulling in has a parent whose node id doesn't show up in the destination repo -- and it doesn't show up because your initial convert changed the nodeids.

Rather than doing two converts, you should do two pulls and a single convert like this:

```
hg init both_unconverted
hg -R both_unconverted pull ../mybranch
hg -R both_unconverted pull ../anotherbranch
hg convert --filemap myfilemap both_unconverted both_converted
```

That way you're not trying to graft the new branch onto already modified changesets.

It's possible you could get your route to work with a --splicemap, but I'm not certain and the suggestion above does the same thing more simply.